# Не рассчитывает элементы массива при вводе большого числа.В чём проблема?

Tags: java, массивы

Задача такова : "Вывести на экран все простые числа до N" (N - вводить в консоль).При вводе больших чисел , программа не выводит результат на экран.Подскажите ,пожалуйста , почему так получается.
Вот код:`package com.company;

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    // 7. Напишите программу, которая вычислит простые числа в пределах от 1 до N.
    //   (Опционально) Дополните программу так, чтобы она вычисляла составные числа.

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println("Введите предельное число");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int lim = input.nextInt();

        getArrayOfPrimals(lim);

    }

    public static void getArrayOfPrimals(int limit) {

        int index = 0;
        int[] array = new int[limit]; // сюда будут заноситься простые числа

        int amountOfDividers = 0;

        for (int integers = 1; integers <= limit; integers++) {

            for (int dividers = 1; dividers <= integers; dividers++) {

                if (integers % dividers == 0) {

                    amountOfDividers++;

                } else {
                }
            }

            if (amountOfDividers > 2) {
            } else {

                array[index] = integers;
                index++;

            }

            amountOfDividers = 0;
        }


        int[] arrayNormal = new int[index];

        for (int elementNumber = 0; elementNumber < index; elementNumber++) {

            if (array[elementNumber] != 0) {

                arrayNormal[elementNumber] = array[elementNumber];

            }

            else  {  }

            }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayNormal));

    }
}
```

PS: Да , знаю !Да ,кривой!Учусь....

Comment: `Да , знаю !Да ,кривой!Учусь....` – не ставьте пробел перед знаком препинания (кроме тире). Зато всегда ставьте после (кроме дефиса). :) Ну и в целом незачем оправдываться, нам это не требуется, чтобы вам ответить. :)

Answer (score 0):

При вводе насколько больших чисел?

1. Возможно программа не выводит результат на экран, потому что расчет происходит очень долго (программа завершает своё выполнение?). Всё выглядит так, что мы можем получить нечеловеческий большое количество итераций.
2. Вы получаете java.lang.OutOfMemoryError? Тогда проблема в том, что для данной виртуальной машины, при данных стартовых параметрах (размер heap), мы задали слишком большой размер массива.

Comment: 1.Врдяли
2.Нет, ошибки вообще нет никакаой.Программа будто-бы ждёт ввода (чего-либо).Попробуйте скомпилировать и запустить у себя.

Comment: Если добавить в массив больше 1.000.000 элементов, то расчет будет производиться уже далеко не одну минуту(это конечно относительно и зависит от проца).
При добавлении миллиона элементов, у нас только внешний цикл выполниться миллион раз. А количество итераций внутреннего цикла мы можем найти по сумме членов арифметической прогрессии. Имея массив длинной в миллион элементов мы получим 500.000.000.000 итераций. Я могу ошибаться, конечно.
Нужно проверить. Я всё-таки полагаю, что программа продолжает работать и считать. Можно попробовать засечь.

Comment: Чтобы подтвердить гипотезу:
перед циклом - long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
после цикла - long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
Соответственно разница (time2 - time1) это количество миллисекунд потраченных на операцию. Вот что вышло: при добавлении 10.000 элементов(э) на операцию ушло 239мс или 0.2с, 50.000э - 5868мс - 5.8с, 100.000э - 23502мс или 23,5с, и наконец контрольный замер и 1.000.000 элементов - прошло 24 минуты а операция всё ещё выполняется. Необходимое для работы этого алгоритма время, при увеличении размера массива растёт в геометрической прогрессии.

Comment: Спасибо:) ... и наконец контрольный замер и 1.000.000 элементов - прошло 24 минуты а операция всё ещё выполняется...- на этом моменте улыбнулся)